# Swift Custom Cell creating your own Cell with labels

Tags: ios, swift, custom-cell

I've just started to use Swift as a prorgamming language and i've run into a problem with Custom cells.

When i try to create custom cells, and then go forward and try to design them the way i need them ( with Style set to Custom ) everything looks good. Now i don't know how to put specific data into them, since all tutorials i found used the style option "basic" where they only have a text label to which they assign their data.

Now for me, when i "control drag" my labels into my code, i give them specific names such as "dateLabel" or "sourceLabel" in order to insert the data correctly.

now i'm not sure, and couldn't find any answers that worked, on how to recall my custom made labels so that i can assign my data to them...

Maybe someone of you could help me with this, since i'm pretty sure it's a simple problem but i coudln't find any resources to this ^^

[image]

hopefully the font isn't to small, i just wanted you guys to see the erros i get.

I used the following tutorial as a guide line, since it was the only one that worked just the way this guy did it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qE8olxB3Kk

I checked the identifier and he is set correctly and i can't find anything online on how i have to properly refer to my own labels with their correct names.

any help would be appreciated  :)

Comment: To use a "custom" cell you also need to create a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`, which you then hook your labels to & set the cell prototype's class to in your storyboard. The errors you're seeing tell you that a normal UITableViewCell, which is what you're creating & returning from that method, doesn't have properties that match the custom labels you created. Where you `dequeue as!` you need to tell it it's your custom cell class. Maybe look for tutorials on custom cell subclasses. BTW, the same basic concepts & process apply to making custom UICollectionView cells as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1. Create a custom table view cell class that extends `UITableViewCell`. In my example, the custom table view cell class is called `MyCustomTableViewCell`.
2. Update your storyboard's cell so that it uses your custom table view cell class. Go to the `Identity Inspector` and set the *Class* value to the name of your custom table view cell class. 
   [image: Set Custom Cell Class in Identity Inspector]
3. Update your storyboard's cell and give it a ***reuse identity*** value. Go to the `Attributes Inspector` and set the *Identifier* value. For example, I gave my cell an Identifier value of `MyCustomCell`. 
   [image: Set the Reuse Identity of your Cell]
4. Control drag the cell's labels into your new custom table view cell class (i.e., the `MyCustomTableViewCell` class).

---

Once you have done the above steps, you will be able to access the labels when you *dequeue* your cell in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. As the code snippet below shows, you will need to: 1) get the cell using the *reuse identifier* you established in the steps above and 2) cast to your custom table view cell class.

For example, here's what your custom table view cell would look like if you named it `MyCustomTableViewCell`. This is after you created the class and control dragged your labels into this class.

```
class MyCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {    
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sourceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Your `ViewController` could look like this:

```
// NOTE: I subclassed UITableViewController since it provides the
// delegate and data source protocols. Consider doing this.
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    // You do NOT need your UILabels since they moved to your
    // custom cell class.

    // ...
    // Omitting your other methods in this code snippet for brevity.
    // ... 

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Use your cell's reuse identifier and cast the result
        // to your custom table cell class. 
        let article = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCell

        // You should have access to your labels; assign the values.
        article.categoryLabel?.text = "something"            
        article.dateLabel?.text = "something"            
        article.sourceLabel?.text = "something"            
        article.titleLabel?.text = "something"            

        return article
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose  we dont create custom tableview cell class , just use default UITableViewCell class and fetching label from custom cell using tag ! is It possible ?? M getting fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. Please clarify this . (Note* -By creating custom cell i did and working fine )

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. The default [`UITableViewCell`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/) has three fields: `textLabel`, `detailTextLabel` and `imageView`. If you use the default then no need to use a custom cell class.