# How to change 2 UIButton Images with click action in tableviewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have working 2 `buttons` on `tableview cell` I got action with `sender`, but I need to change button images each click  for example:

On load:

```
button1image = user.png
button2image = empty.png
```

If user click `button 1`:

```
button1image = empty.png
button2image = user.png
```

If user clicks `button 2`:

```
button1image = user.png
button2image = empty.png
```

In my `tableviewcell`:

```
  cell.button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.clickbutton1(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

  cell.button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.clickbutton2(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

In `ViewController`:

```
func clickbutton1(sender:UIButton) {

        let buttonRow = sender.tag
}

  func clickbutton2(sender:UIButton) {


        let buttonRow = sender.tag

}
```

Also I can change `buttons` inside images like this:

```
  sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"empty.png"), forState:UIControlState.Normal)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?... it is not clear.

Comment: @RoyK i added example if 's you can see top side , i need to connect 2 buttons in each cell if button 1 click will be change button 1 image to new and also button 2 image to old. need to change 2 image between 2 buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this, create 2 string instance that contain image name and use that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this way.

```
var button1image = "user.png"
var button2image = "empty.png"
```

Now in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
cell.button1.setImage(UIImage(named: button1image), forState: .Normal)
cell.button2.setImage(UIImage(named: button2image), forState: .Normal)
```

Now just change the value of variable inside button action and just reload the tableView.

```
func clickbutton1(sender:UIButton) {

    let buttonRow = sender.tag
    button1image = "empty.png"
    button2image = "user.png"
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func clickbutton2(sender:UIButton) {

    let buttonRow = sender.tag
    button1image = user.png
    button2image = empty.png
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom UITableViewCell and then you will be able to do whatever you want :
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004189/swift-custom-cell-creating-your-own-cell-with-label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004189/swift-custom-cell-creating-your-own-cell-with-labels)s